# BizTalk functoid to get most recent date?

Tags: datetime, biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-mapper

I have a schema with child elements cType, cDate.
In a map I have a loop functoid bringing out all elements where cType = 'registration', this all works fine.

I also want to add to that same map a functoid which, after filtering out the 'registration' types, then only maps across the one with the most recent date.

I see there is a Max functoid but I'm guessing this is not for dates.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Yes the Max and Cumulative Max functoids are only for numerics and not dates.  You will probably have to do it via custom XSLT in a scripting functoid.  Another option is as described here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7fb080fb-6ce2-47e2-927a-47b76eb4cba4/how-to-get-min-and-max-date-in-the-map?forum=biztalkgeneral

Answer (score 1):

Yes the Max and Cumulative Max functoids are only for numeric values and not dates.

You have two options.  Write it as a Custom XSLT, or use a bunch of functoids as below as per [How to get Min and max date in the map](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7fb080fb-6ce2-47e2-927a-47b76eb4cba4/how-to-get-min-and-max-date-in-the-map?forum=biztalkgeneral)

[image]

1. A **Date** functoid
2. A **Scripting** functoid with the code shown below, with inputs cDate and the Date functoid
3. A **Equal** functoid with constant value **registration** and input cType
4. A **Value Mapping** functoid with input the Equal and the scripting functoids
5. A **Cumulative Maximum** functoid with input the Value Mapping functoid
6. A **Equal** functoid with input the Cumulative Maximum and Scripting functoids
7. A **And** Functoid with inputs the two equal functoids.

Code in the scripting functoid

```
public int DateDiff(DateTime cDate, DateTime today)
{
    return (cDate - today).Days;
}
```

Basically if the cType = Registration AND the date is the maximum registration date, map that across.

Input

```
<ns0:Registrations xmlns:ns0="http://Scratch.Registration">
  <Registration>
    <cType>registration</cType>
    <cDate>1999-05-31</cDate>
  </Registration>
  <Registration>
    <cType>registration</cType>
    <cDate>2016-05-31</cDate>
  </Registration>
  <Registration>
    <cType>not</cType>
    <cDate>2016-08-31</cDate>
  </Registration>
</ns0:Registrations>
```

Output

```
<ns0:Registrations xmlns:ns0="http://Scratch.Registration">
    <Registration>
        <cType>registration</cType>
        <cDate>2016-05-31</cDate>
    </Registration>
</ns0:Registrations>
```